# Javascript Do while loop stops after one iteration only

Tags: javascript, iteration, do-while, break

I have a do while loop that stops after one iteration only, although the condition has a false result more than once. 
Another thing - everything that comes after the while statement isn't executed.
The code is very long so here is an example of the test condition:

```
do {
  let x = 0;  
  let y = 3;

  for (let j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
    if(j%2==0){
      x++;
    }
  }
} while (x < y);
```

Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is x is not defined. let has got a block scope. and you have declared x and y in do block which doesn't have scope after the block. If you want to use them in the while condition place them either outside or change the let to var.

You are ending up with an error and hence, the code doesn't execute after the while. To sense the error surround it with a try catch.

```js
do {
  let x = 0;
  let y = 3;
  for (let j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
    if (j % 2 == 0) {
      x++;
    }
  }
} while (x < y);
```

```js
do {
  var x = 0;
  var y = 3;
  for (let j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
    if (j % 2 == 0) {
      x++;
    }
  }
} while (x < y);
console.log(x)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I would just define the `let`s outside the `do`... or, if you insist the `var`s. Although it is valid JavaScript to assign a variable in a block while testing for it outside the block, some editors will produce an error, unless you allow it... therefore I would avoid the practice and define the variable where both blocks have access.

Answer (score 1):

scope of x and y inside the do statement means it's not there for the while statement. But your code is looping multiple times

```js
let x=0;  
let y=3;
do{

 
 for (let j=0; j<9; j++){
 if(j%2==0){x++;}
 console.log(x,y) 
   }
   
 }while(x<y);
```

```js
   
do{
  let x=0;  
  let y=3;

 
 for (let j=0; j<9; j++){
 if(j%2==0){x++;}
 console.log(x,y) 
   }
   
 }while(x<y);
```